# Frequency spectrum in PLECS for CM noise measurement

Tags: buck, emc, fourier, common-mode

I am performing a simulation to measure the common mode noise in a buck converter. I have three models, an ideal buck, a non-ideal buck with parasitic capacitors, and a CM equivalent circuit to compare the CM noise from the equivalent circuit and from the non-ideal circuit. This is being done to check if the CM equivalent circuit is accurate or not.

I did this in Simulink. I am also trying in LTspice and in PLECS. To replace the noise source, the CM noise from the ideal buck is given as the noise source in the equivalent circuit.

My doubt is:

1. In LTspice, there is no 'controlled voltage source' option as in Simulink, so I directly fed the noise to the circuit. I tried using the dependent voltage source component, but the output of it was not coming accurate. What can be done in this case?

[image: CM Buck LTSpice]

2. PLECS has a 'controlled voltage source' option, but when I connect that it gives so many errors everywhere the voltage source is directly connected to a capacitor. This however doesn't happen in LTspice or Simulink. Why is that?

[image: CM Buck Plecs]

In order to make the simulation run in PLECS, I have to add some resistors in these paths, but I am unsure about the outputs as then the equivalent circuit won't be accurate because of the resistors.

3. Also in PLECS, when I take the Fourier spectrum of the respective voltages to see the CM noise frequency spectrum, it comes out a bit differently than in LTspice. The frequency axis doesn't seem to change to the log scale. What can be done to get a spectrum like LTspice? (Image attached: 4)

[image: CM freq spectrum LTSpice]

[image: CM freq spectrum plecs]

Comment: Not much here, but using voltage sources to charge capacitors with no series resistors is a short circuit if the voltage has steps. And it has steps, maybe no more than the difference of adjacent samples, but they are steps. Plexim at least warns you of a math impossibility. The idea of measuring voltages of a circuit and injecting them with ideal sources to a emission path model stinks. The outer world and the emission paths should be integrated to the circuit model itself to make me believe it has a possibility to be a valid simulation.

Comment: @EdHalfsunk This is a sort of an initial circuit that will in turn include all other parasitics such as L, switch, and also the bus bar. However, in order to tackle the problem of modeling the equivalent circuit, at first only the parasitic caps have been considered and then the equivalent circuit has been formed. This is for simplification and ease of understanding. Please suggest any other method that would work in case of modeling the noise source.

Comment: Still busy. But you will get something. The subject is tricky, as you see by counting all comments and answers cumulated in 24 hours. Meanwhile find some common mode noise measurement setups. An example: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/separating-common-mode-and-differential-mode-emissions-in-conducted-emissions-testing.html You see there's 2...3 different grounds - the power supply circuit ground, the power supply housing and the external world ground. The interesting noise component is between the DUT in or out wires and the external world ground - Is this already known?

Comment: @EdHalfsunk yes. I had referred to this source before as well. The place where I am stuck is how to model the noise source with common-mode noise voltage in it. i.e. even after we find the equivalent circuit, in the place of the switch we have to insert a CM vtg source. So that after inserting this source and running the model, the CM emissions from the non-ideal ckt and the equivalent circuit would match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For a start:*

Labeled connections you have used work differently in Plecs and LTspice.

LTspice: If you have a wire which stops to labeled output connector named X and then somewhere there's an input connector named also X, you actually have a wire between the connectors. Every part and wire behind the input X becomes a part of the circuit where the output X is. As well they could be inserted directly to the 1st circuit.

Plecs: You measure a voltage with a voltage picking block and output the result as a in-simulation control signal, say Vab_I. Then you recreate in your leak path model the same voltage with a controlled voltage source.

You get warnings "a capacitor connected in parallel with a voltage source". That's because changing stepwise a voltage of a capacitor needs infinite current. You silenced the warnings by inserting series resistors. That unfortunately is low-pass filtering which surely affects the result. But the result got by measuring a voltage and injecting it to a leak path model would be crap even in case the simulator could use average sample period currents to make the capacitor voltages to follow the controlled voltage sources. That's because the leak path parts are physical parts of the whole circuit and they affect what the circuit actually does. Your attempt to inject the circuit quantities to the leak path model is an attempt to deny it, you assume that the circuit works as it would work without all those stray parts.

LTspice does not talk dirty, no matter you connect a charged capacitor to another through a timed switch. That's because there's some small resistance assumed by default to avoid divisions by zero.

*The ideal buck converter:*

[image]

The switching operation doesn't emit noise if the circuit is this (no leakages nor other stray quantities, no wires long enough to behave as radiating antennas). Even the capacitor C1 is here useless because the ideal DC source keeps a certain voltage   between the input nodes P and M. Between nodes A and B there's rectangular pulses as the switch is in turns ON and OFF. It causes no emissions because nodes M and B are the same circuit ground. A and B are not by any means connected to the external world. The load voltage has some ripple due the pulsed operation, but L1 and C2 can in ideal case filter it to as low as wanted - have only big enough C2.

The questioner wanted to simulate the noise that a less than ideal buck regulator emits along the DC input wires to the external world. If the parts are non-ideal and there's stray quantities like capacitances, inductances and mutual inductances the emission can really make the whole regulator useless. There can be direct radiation from the circuit. In addition there can be a substantial high frequency voltage component between the (non-ideal) DC input wires - that's the differential mode conducted noise and there can be also conducted common mode noise. It exists as a high frequency voltage from both DC input nodes to the environment ground.

Formally we can think the conducted common mode noise as the AC component of the average voltage from the DC input nodes to the environment ground.

Of course, conducted emissions can also come out along the DC output wires, but the questioner started from what's emitted along  the DC input wires and especially the common mode component. That's understandable, because the conducted common mode noise can cause harm as far as where the DC comes from and even further, because the DC feeding cable works as an antenna. The next drawing shows an elementary model of *a non-ideal buck regulator*:

[image]

There's inserted 2 capacitors Ca and Cb to the environment ground from nodes A and B. in addition the switch is changed to a real component, because an ideal switch between capacitors would have an infinite peak current. C1 is now 100% necessary, because  the induction and transmission line effects in the long DC feed wires would otherwise make the DC input voltage highly unstable and the behaviour of the circuit would be practically unpredictable.

How Ca and Cb cause emission? That's simple. The environment ground is connected to a capacitive voltage divider. If Ca > 0 and Cb is less than infinite the pulses between nodes A and B really generate some AC signal to both input nodes Vp and Vm. That's the common mode noise. With an advanced 2-input measuring instrument one can measure it by letting the instrument measure and calculate the AC-component of (Vp+Vm)/2 where the voltages are measured against the environment ground. The power spectrum of that (Vp+Vm)/2 is the most interesting measure of the emission.

The differential mode conducted noise would be respectively the difference Vp-Vm. It also exists, because C1 is not infinite and it has some series resistance and inductance. It cannot keep the input DC voltage fully stable.

In this phase a couple of things needs some attention:

1. Ca and Cb are charged and discharged through the non-ideal switching components SW1 and D1. Their turn-on-turn-off behaviour, their resistances and of course, the capacitances Ca and Cb affect radically how rapidly the voltage between nodes A and B change. That affects as radically the spectrum of the common mode noise.
2. The "long wires" for DC input and the "environment ground" are quite as vague things as possible. Capacitances Ca and Cb depend on the placements of the items in the circuit and on the ground plane. It's useless to expect any repeatable noise measurement results if there's no attempt to standardize the wires and the environment ground.

The next image is used to explain the simplest possible measurement standardization:

[image]

To get some repeatability to the noise measurements the DC source wiring can be isolated from the circuit by inserting a low-pass filter to the wires. The DC voltage does not disturb the measuring equipment if the equipment inputs are connected capacitively to the DC input of the regulator. Resistors Rs1 and Rs2 have the same resistance. They are there to offer a certain standard load to the noise voltages. They can be the common 50 ohm measuring equipment inputs. The lowpass filters and the parts for DC blocking are together called Line impedance stabilizing network (=LISN).

The environment ground is a big metal plane below the circuit.

The allowed noise emission limits are declared in numerous different standards. For example power supplies for aviation applications have different limits than what's allowed for home entertainment devices. The standards also define how the measurements should be performed in compliance checking procedures. That contains the LISN, environment ground, possible anechoing chambers and the specs for the measuring equipment.

This equipment advertisement https://www.tekbox.com/product/LISN_Basics_and_Overview.pdf shows some practical noise measurement systems.

Standards are complex documents which have needed a massive amount of effort to get developed, so do not expect you can automatically get them for free. You very likely can find only some snippets in the web.

*The reliability of the simulations:*

By simulating the whole circuit in my noise measuring visualization drawing it's in theory possible to predict what the measurements would give. The LISN should be included because it affects the result.

I'm afraid the model is far too simple for reliable estimation, because it takes into the account only 2 stray capacitances and the non-ideal switching in SW1 and D1. Capacitances Ca and Cb depend on the physical circuit layout and the circuit placement in relative to the environment ground plane. A metal housing of the circuit makes the case even more tricky. It would be essential to know as a circuit model how the metal case is coupled to the environment ground and to nodes A and B. To create some estimation value to the simulation this all should be the same as what they would be in a real measuring system which obeys the interesting standard.

Every wire has resistance and inductance and there's stray capacitances and mutual inductances between all parts and all wires. A geometry and electromagnetic field aware high end RF-simulator could really take all this into the account, but the modelling effort would be huge. I have never tried anything in that league. Although complex, measuring from a real circuit is much easier, because all those stray quantities are what they are and behave just as they behave and the environment ground and the LISN affect as they affect when they are built, connected and placed as the used standard says - no need to model any non-idealities.

Sorry for being unable to give much more than a bloated compilation of my comments.

Comment: thank you for such an elaborate explanation. In the last point, i.e. reliability of simulations, indeed I will go for measuring the parasitics of the board, if not, then at least the parameters extracted using tools like HFSS or CST MWS. However, the hurdle still lies i.e. of modeling the source. Even if I consider the parasitics accurately, how should the source be simulated? Some papers suggest a 1V AC source, some suggest a pulse source of trapezoidal nature. Some have given the sources but not indicated what is the nature of it, exactly. Would you be able to help in this area?

Comment: Excuse me, but what source? In a switchmode power supply the noise source is the whole circuit. My ultimate CaCbSW1D1 simplification assumed that the voltage between A and B is the only important one. Vab is the result of the operation of the  circuit including the the non-idealities of SW1 and  D1 and Ca and Cb. It cannot be replaced with any assumed other pulse form. Maybe you must reread this: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/how-to-get-the-best-results-using-ltspice-part-1.html At least its publisher should be taken seriously. There's not tried to skip the just mentioned fact .

Comment: Source as in the images attached: Where all images illustrate the common mode equivalent circuit, the switching node has been replaced (in the equivalent circuit) by noise sources which would make the eq-ckt behave as the complete detailed ckt with parasitics. 1st paper employs a dc voltage source, 2nd and AC source, and 3rd a trapezoidal pulse source.  [![Paper1_vtg source][1]][1]
[![Paper2_AC source][2]][2]
[![Paper3_trapezoidal_source][3]][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nwBL.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbwRO.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Udy.png

Comment: I cannot believe the marked (red) voltage in drawing 1 is constant DC. I can imagine easily the image tries to assure the CM noise voltage contains many components which are born in different processes in the motor drive system. The original text only tells if Vcm,b is assumed to have some form, too. Paper 2 visualizes the frequency response evaluation of from one pulse voltage place to the environment. The actual noise generating pulse voltage is still unhandled. Image 3 assumes already solved pulses. The circuit non-idealities define their actual forms. This is only a model of measurement.

Comment: @ORion (continued) You still wanted the right source voltage waveform which would produce the proper simulated noise emission, when fed through a leakage path model . I've run out of ideas how to tell that just that waveform should be at first calculated by simulating the whole circuit with its non-idealities including 1) the leakage path model and 2) the environment model, at least the LISN. Any guessed waveform will generate a wrong emission spectrum except in case you happen to have some incredible luck.

Comment: Yes, I tried to analyze my circuit a bit more and I successfully am able to match the common mode voltage from a non-ideal circuit with the equivalent circuit. For starters, the inductor had to be removed and for even more simplicity I also removed the load side parasitics. Non-ideal switching node voltage was emulated which acted as a noise source in the CM eq ckt. As far as the plecs output is concerned. I will be taking out the .csv data and converting that to an actual spectrum with a log freq axis and dBuV amplitude axis.